# Proof that powers of a matrix commute with the matrix itself

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, field-theory

The end goal is to prove that, for a square matrix $A$, nullity$(A^k)\leq$ nullity$(A^{k+1})$. Here is what I have:

Let $x$ be an element of the null space of $A^k$. That is, $A^kx=0$. Then, $(A^{k+1})x=(AA^k)x=A(A^kx)=A(0)=0$. Thus, $x$ is an element of the null space of $A^{k+1}$, so NS$(A^k)\subseteq$ NS$(A^{k+1})$, implying the desired result.

I believe this proof is complete, however I'd like to justify the claim that $A^{k+1}=AA^k$. I know this should be intuitive, but I'm having a hard time actually explaining it. I am familiar with group theory and field theory, so an approach from one of those areas is more than welcome, but I'd also like to see the purely linear algebra approach.

Comment: What is your definition of $A^k$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This follows directly from the associativity of matrix multiplication. Matrix multiplication is equivalent to composition of linear operators, which is clearly associative.

Comment: Yep, dumb question. Associative multiplication implies commutativity of powers. I'll leave this here in case someone else is forgetting simple properties of matrices while working on a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be a bit unhappy with $A^{k+1}=AA^k$, I'll assume that your definition of $A^k$ for non-negative integers $k$ is inductively
$$A^0=I\ ,\quad A^{k+1}=A^kA\ .$$
Then you can do an induction proof - I'll leave the formal details to you but the main idea is
$$A^{k+1}=A^kA=(AA^{k-1})A=A(A^{k-1}A)=AA^k\ .$$

Comment: Your second step here makes the assumption that I was trying to prove (that $A^k=AA^{k-1}$). That's okay though, I realized that this doesn't require a rigorous proof as matrices have multiplicative associativity.

Comment: It makes the assumption for the previous case, i.e., $k-1$ instead of $k$.  That's how induction works.

Comment: I agree I was making assumptions about what you wanted, but as in Eric Wofsey's comment, the real point is, what is your definition of $A^k$?